# Emacs: is there a way I can get a list of custom tags - and navigate thru them?

Tags: emacs, tags, bookmarks, cedet, emacs-ecb

Suppose I have a file with the following marks (or call it tags):

test.el:

```
;; =====
;; gnus:

some code here

;; ====
;; ECB:

some code here

;; =====
;; code:

some code here
```

(in elisp)

test.py:

```
# ========
# imports:

some code here

# =====
# defs:

some code here

# =====
# args:

some code here
```

(in python)

So I'd like to have a buffer which would list such tags (or call it marks) for a given buffer/file. And it should also facilitate navigation thru this tags in some way - with a mouse or keybindings (something similar to the `table of contents` functionality of `rest-mode`).

I wanted to solve this problem by modifing some etags function. But couldn't find one (that would be a solution since ECB shows etags nicely in a buffer - just as I wanted).

Some other solution might have been using bookmarks - but bookmarks are not file-specific. They are system-specific. That is in bookmark-list You have all the bookmarks - while I wanted to get the bookmarks of the given file only.

Comment: I don't use ECB, but is that "tags" as in an etags/ctags TAGS file? Or something specific to ECB? If the former, I strongly doubt you can make it index comments. There are bookmark enhancements around, though, so perhaps there are ways to improve the bookmark workflow.

Comment: I'm even more confused about your definition of "tags" now that you've added outline-minor-mode into the mix. That's *definitely* not outline terminology. Your question remains ambiguous.

Comment: @phils: You right - my edit has nothing to do with tags. It's just another way of attacking the problem of navigartion thru custom marks (or call it tags). Perhaps I should re-formulate the question.

Comment: @phils: I've completely re-formulated my question.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but I know Emacs [`org-mode`](http://orgmode.org/) supports this feature. In the worst case, a code lift from there can give you the desired functionality. Also, have you seen [this page](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Customizing-the-display.html) and [this one](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Updating-Methods_002dwindow.html) from the documentation? It describes customizing your methods window, which you could theoretically rework into a tag browser if you, for example, collapse all tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Emacs Lisp example code, I solved it with the following that could be added to a hook for emacs-lisp-mode, and should be easy to tweak for other languages.

```
(make-local-variable 'outline-regexp)
(setq outline-regexp ";; =+\n;; ")
(make-local-variable 'outline-heading-end-regexp)
(setq outline-heading-end-regexp ":\n")
(outline-minor-mode 1)
```

You can now use standard outline mode, which has keybindings like this:

```
C-c @ C-p  -> prevous header
C-c @ C-n  -> next header

C-c @ C-t  -> hide code between headers
C-c @ C-a  -> show all the code between headers
```

If you temporarily hide the headers, you will get an outline of your buffer, move where you want, then show the code again.

For python, just replace the ;; in the regexp with #.

`outline-mode` comes with Emacs, and is documented there if you need more information.